# What's the difference between defining class methods in a namespace block and defining them using ::

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

For example:

```
// Example.h
namespace MyExample
{
     class Example
     {
         void Print() const;
     };
}
```

What's the difference between doing this:

```
// Example.cpp
namespace MyExample
{
    Example::Print() const
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And doing this:

```
// Example.cpp
MyExample::Example::Print() const
{
    ...
}
```

What's the advantages / disadvantages of both?

Comment: There's no difference, it's just a lot more verbose in the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference for the compiler.

However, you will note that some IDE, when generating code, will prefer the second solution (such as Eclipse CDT) :

- When reading the definition, it is immediately clear in which namespace the function is, no need to scroll up the file
- It avoid confusion with nested namespaces
- It limits the nesting of the code in your editor (in solution 1, each namespace block adds a whole new indentation for the code defined in it)
- If you grep for the namespace name in the source file, you will more easily find which functions are declared in it

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same technically. However when you've many functions of that namespace to be defined in the file, instead of qualifying each with the namespace name you could do the former to avoid the extra typing, if you don't particularly enjoy cracking your knuckles.

Of course, the latter form has better readability for some and it's subjective.